# Input from c++ string to batch file

Tags: c++, batch-file

I want to input the batch file variable from c++, but i search for many help also can't be done...

```
    system("bin\\data\\locker.bat");
```

The batch file is asking an input, but how i get the value from c++ and insert to the batch file?
I use c++ to open this batch, but i cant insert the password required by using c++.
Batch :

```
cls 
@ECHO OFF 
title Folder Private 
if EXIST "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK 
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER 
:CONFIRM 
echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N) 
set/p "cho=>" 
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==y goto LOCK 
if %cho%==n goto END 
if %cho%==N goto END 
echo Invalid choice. 
goto CONFIRM 
:LOCK 
ren Private "HTG Locker" 
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker" 
echo Folder locked 
goto End 
:UNLOCK 
echo Enter password to unlock folder 
set/p "pass=>" 
if NOT %pass%== PASSWORD_GOES_HERE goto FAIL 
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker" 
ren "HTG Locker" Private 
echo Folder Unlocked successfully 
goto End 
:FAIL 
echo Invalid password 
goto end 
:MDLOCKER 
md Private 
echo Private created successfully 
goto End 
:End
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

**1:** You should quote both operands of an `if` comparison. If an operand expands to nothing then it will cause a syntax error if unquoted.

**2:** You should use the `:eof` implicit label rather than defining your own `End` label.

**3:** You should use `echo.` rather than `echo` with a space separator. This is not technically necessary in your case, since you only have literal messages, but in cases where the message consists of only a variable expansion, such as `echo %msg%`, using `echo.%msg%` will print a single blank line, rather than `ECHO is on.`, and it's good to be consistent.

**4:** You should initialize your `set /p` target variables prior to running the `set /p` command; otherwise residual values could mess up the script.

**5:** I admit this is subjective, but I recommend you space out the different sections of your script for readability, rather than keeping it as one unbroken block of code.

**6:** You can pipe input to a script that internally calls `set /p`, although piping a password to a batch script raises unpleasant security questions.

---

So this is how I would rewrite your code (using "pass" for the password):

```
cls
@echo off

title Folder Private

if exist "HTG Locker" goto UNLOCK
if not exist Private goto MDLOCKER

:CONFIRM
echo.Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
set cho=
set /p "cho=>"
if "%cho%"=="Y" goto LOCK
if "%cho%"=="y" goto LOCK
if "%cho%"=="n" goto :eof
if "%cho%"=="N" goto :eof
echo.Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM

:LOCK
ren Private "HTG Locker"
attrib +h +s "HTG Locker"
echo.Folder locked
goto :eof

:UNLOCK
echo.Enter password to unlock folder
set pass=
set /p "pass=>"
if not "%pass%"=="pass" goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "HTG Locker"
ren "HTG Locker" Private
echo.Folder Unlocked successfully
goto :eof

:FAIL
echo.Invalid password
goto :eof

:MDLOCKER
md Private
echo.Private created successfully
```

And the C++ program (using a macro to store the password; alternatively, you could read it from a file and call `sprintf()` to generate the system command string, which may be preferable, since it would obviate the storage of the password in the C++ source and binary):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#define PASSWORD "pass"

int main(void) {
    system("echo." PASSWORD "| locker.bat");
    return 0;
} // end main()
```

Compilation and execution (running `locker.bat` manually first to lock the folder, then running `a.exe` to unlock it):

```
cl a.cpp
## Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
## Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
##
## a.cpp
## Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23026.0
## Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
##
## /out:a.exe
## a.obj
##
.\locker
## Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
## >y
## Folder locked
.\a
## Enter password to unlock folder
## >Folder Unlocked successfully
```

Comment: Thx for your advise!! 
However even though my batch file successfully ran in c++ and able to insert the password, even the "Folder Unlocked successfully" shown, my private file still not shown in the folder, is there any things i miss ?

Comment: What private files? Your script does not do anything with files.

Comment: My batch file function is when it run and insert password, it will create a Private Folder. When it run again, it will ask to lock/hide the folder. I can run normally when i manually click the batch file, but when using c++ code to run it, it provide no action...